# AngularJS: Error while accessing Isolated JS file

Tags: angularjs

Any suggestions or help will be thankful..

//This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="invoice2" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
      <b>Invoice:</b>
      <div>
        Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qty" required >
      </div>
      <div>
        Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" required >
        <select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
          <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>Total:</b>
        <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
          {{invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
        </span><br>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
      </div>
    </div>


       <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Services\Ex1\invoice.js"></script>
       <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Services\Ex1\finance.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>


//This is my invoice.js

angular.module('invoice', ['finance'])
.controller('InvoiceController',['currencyConverter', function InvoiceController(currencyConverter){
    this.qty = 1;
    this.cost = 2;
    this.inCurr = "EURO";
    this.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;

    this.total = function total(outCur){
        return currencyConverter.convert(this.qty*this.cost, this.inCurr, outCur);
    };      

}]);

//This is my finance.js 

var app = angular.module('finance', [])
.factory('currencyConverter', function(){
    var currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
    var usdToForeignRates = {
        USD: 1,
        EUR: 0.74,
        CNY: 6.09
    };

    var convert = function (amnt, inCurr, outCurr){
        return amnt * usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
    }
    return {
        currencies : currencies,
        convert : convert
    };
});
```

/*finance.js is a common file which could be re-usable. Invoice.js file is trying to access the finance.js. I`m getting an error. I have added the error message that I`ve got. Since I`m learning AngularJS new I couldn`t figure it out. */

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?p0=invoice2&p1=Error%3…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179)
    at angular.min.js:6
    at angular.min.js:42
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at g (angular.min.js:41)
    at eb (angular.min.js:46)
    at c (angular.min.js:21)
    at Sc (angular.min.js:22)
    at ue (angular.min.js:20)
    at angular.min.js:331
    at HTMLDocument.b (angular.min.js:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

try loading finance.js first , then invoice.js

```
  <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Services\Ex1\finance.js"></script>
   <script src="D:\Mano\Angular\Services\Ex1\invoice.js"></script>
```